# How to remove items that are not in all the other lists

Tags: python-3.x

In python 3:

I have some sets of lists. One set of lists is a time stamp, the other is a measurement that corresponds to that time. I have 5 lots of these. So let's call the lists: Time1, Time2, Time3, Time4, Time5 and M1, M2, M3, M4, M5. This lists should all be the same size, but unfortunately they are not. I want to loop through all the lists making sure that every Time is in each list, and if it isn't, remove that timestamp from the list and also removing the corresponding measurement value. So I end up with all the lists being off equal length and Time1-5 have all the exact same timestamps in.

What is the most pythonic and quickest way to do this?

So for example:

Original timestamps and corresponding measurements:

Time1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and M1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Time2 = [1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and M2 = [6, 11, 8, 9, 10, 4, 7]

Time3 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M3 = [6, 18, 91, 10, 7]

Time4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and M4 =[50, 16, 72, 18, 9, 10]

Time5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and M5 = [24, 32, 11, 2, 9, 1]

After processing:

Time1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M1 = [5, 6, 8, 9, 10]

Time2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M2 = [6, 11, 9, 10, 4]

Time3 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M3 = [6, 18, 91, 10, 7]

Time4 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M4 = [50, 16, 18, 9, 10]

Time5 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M5 = [24, 32, 2, 9, 1]

Comment: Please share some example data with expected output.

Comment: I have edited question now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed time1, ..., time5, M1, ..., M5 are defined.

I'm sure this is not the quickest way, but works:

```
times = [time1, time2, time3, time4, time5]
Ms = [M1, M2, M3, M4, M5]

def intersection(l):
    l = [set(item) for item in l]
    return set.intersection(*l)

def func():
    if len(times) != len(Ms):
        print("!!! List numbers are not same !!!")
        return None

    time_intersection = intersection(times)

    for i, time in enumerate(times):
        for j, time_stamp in enumerate(time):
            if time_stamp not in time_intersection:
                Ms[i][j] = -1
        #Update
        Ms[i] = [x for x in Ms[i] if x != -1]       
        times[i] = list(time_intersection)  

func()  
print("times:\t" + str(times))
print("Ms:\t" + str(Ms))
```

Output:

```
times:  [[1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]]
Ms:     [[5, 6, 8, 9, 10], [6, 11, 9, 10, 4], [6, 18, 91, 10, 7], [50, 16, 18, 9, 10], [24, 32, 2, 9, 1]]
```

`times` and `Ms` lists are updated. time1, ..., time5, M1, ..., M5 are not updated. You can arrange them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Times = [Time1, Time2, Time3, Time4, Time5]
WantedTime = list(set(Time1).intersection(*Times[1:]))
def TimeToM(Time,M):
    idx = [i for i, x in enumerate(Time) if x in WantedTime]
    return [y for i, y in enumerate(M) if i in idx]
M1 = TimeToM(Time1, M1)
...
Time1, Time2, Time3, Time4, Time5 = [WantedTime for _ in range(len(Times)]
```

Answer (score 0):

- It works on 2.7+ too if you alter the `print` statement
- Removing the last print statement you will get exactly what you wanted
- Automatically works if you have more variables `Time, M`
- Change the Range if you have more variables
- Less code

### Code:

```
Time1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];M1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];Time2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];M2 = [6, 11, 8, 9, 10, 4, 7];Time3 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];M3 = [6, 18, 91, 10, 7];Time4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];M4 =[50, 16, 72, 18, 9, 10];Time5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];M5 = [24, 32, 11, 2, 9, 1]

common_Time = set(Time1)
for i in range(2,6):
     common_Time = common_Time & set(eval('Time'+str(i)))

for i in range(1,6):
     for index, value in enumerate(set(eval('Time'+str(i)))-common_Time):
         tmp_key=eval('Time'+str(i)).index(value)-index
         del eval('M'+str(i))[tmp_key]
     locals()['Time'+str(i)] = list(common_Time)
     print("Time{indx} = {time} and M{indx} = {m}".format(indx=str(i), time=str(list(common_Time)),m =str(locals()['M'+str(i)])))
```

### Output:

```
Time1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M1 = [5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
Time2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M2 = [6, 11, 9, 10, 4]
Time3 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M3 = [6, 18, 91, 10, 7]
Time4 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M4 = [50, 16, 18, 9, 10]
Time5 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6] and M5 = [24, 32, 2, 9, 1]
```

Comment: Please accept as an answer, and upvote if you are satisfied by the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Given that t1, t2 ... t5 and m1, m2... m5 are already provided, here is a possible solution using list comprehension (too many)

```
# Create a nested list of time and measurement
t = [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5]
m=[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5]

# Find intersection of all values time
common = set(t[0]).intersection(*t)

# Create a dictionary by mapping elements of respective time and 
# measurement [t1:m1, t2:m2 and so on]
tm = [dict(zip(keys, vals)) for keys, vals in zip(t,m)]

# Get keys which are in common
t = [[k for k in d.keys() if k in common] for d in tm]

# Get values which respective keys in t
m = [[d[k] for k in d.keys() if k in common]for d in tm]
```